# Google Vision - Batch Image Annotation, map result to request images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-vision

I'm using Google Vision to detect text in images (on my backend written in kotlin).
I want to do a batch request with multiple images from a web url but the problem I'm facing is how to know what results maps to what image in the request?

Can I rely on Google to return the result in the same order as I put them into the batch request?

Currently I do not get any information in the response that I can use to figure out to what image the annotated text belongs to. And it's important that the text can be mapped to the correct image.

If you need more information please let me know and I'll provide it to you.

Answer (score 0):

The responses are in the same order as they are in the request.